# Удаление атрибута "disabled" и назначение нового класса стилей

Tags: javascript, css, dom

Подскажите как доделать чтобы правильно работало? Если установили checkbox, то на кнопку можно нажать, также применяется новый класс со стилями. Если сняли checkbox, то удалили новый класс со стилями и заблокировали кнопку.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('submit-form');
document.getElementById('check').onclick = function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    // если checked, то применить новые стили к кнопке и отключить атрибут "disabled"...
    btn.removeAttribute(disabled);
    btn.classList.add('.button_checkin');

  } else {
    btn.setAttribute(disabled);
    btn.classList.remove('.button_checkin');
    // если не checked, то снять новые стили.
  }
};
```

```css
input+span {
  display: inline;
  line-height: normal;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode', sans-serif;
  font-size: .8em;
  color: #333;
}

.application-form-footer__button {
  cursor: default;
  width: 278px;
  height: 55px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode', sans-serif;
  color: #a1a2a7;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 241, 234, 0.55);
  -webkit-border-radius: 17px;
  -moz-border-radius: 17px;
  -ms-border-radius: 17px;
  border-radius: 17px;
  background: #efeef3;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#efeef3 0%, #eeedf2 11%, #ecebf0 13%, #edecf2 15%, #e6e7ec 38%, #e8e7ed 45%, #dddee3 66%, #dddee3 75%, #dbdce1 77%, #e1e2e7 91%, #ecedf2 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#efeef3 0%, #eeedf2 11%, #ecebf0 13%, #edecf2 15%, #e6e7ec 38%, #e8e7ed 45%, #dddee3 66%, #dddee3 75%, #dbdce1 77%, #e1e2e7 91%, #ecedf2 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#efeef3 0%, #eeedf2 11%, #ecebf0 13%, #edecf2 15%, #e6e7ec 38%, #e8e7ed 45%, #dddee3 66%, #dddee3 75%, #dbdce1 77%, #e1e2e7 91%, #ecedf2 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(#efeef3 0%, #eeedf2 11%, #ecebf0 13%, #edecf2 15%, #e6e7ec 38%, #e8e7ed 45%, #dddee3 66%, #dddee3 75%, #dbdce1 77%, #e1e2e7 91%, #ecedf2 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#efeef3', endColorstr='#ecedf2', GradientType=0);
}

.button_checkin {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #000;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(253, 253, 253, 1) 11%, rgba(246, 246, 246, 1) 28%, rgba(245, 245, 245, 1) 49%, rgba(241, 241, 241, 1) 51%, rgba(240, 240, 240, 1) 53%, rgba(234, 234, 234, 1) 66%, rgba(232, 232, 232, 1) 77%, rgba(239, 239, 239, 1) 91%, rgba(254, 254, 254, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(253, 253, 253, 1) 11%, rgba(246, 246, 246, 1) 28%, rgba(245, 245, 245, 1) 49%, rgba(241, 241, 241, 1) 51%, rgba(240, 240, 240, 1) 53%, rgba(234, 234, 234, 1) 66%, rgba(232, 232, 232, 1) 77%, rgba(239, 239, 239, 1) 91%, rgba(254, 254, 254, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(253, 253, 253, 1) 11%, rgba(246, 246, 246, 1) 28%, rgba(245, 245, 245, 1) 49%, rgba(241, 241, 241, 1) 51%, rgba(240, 240, 240, 1) 53%, rgba(234, 234, 234, 1) 66%, rgba(232, 232, 232, 1) 77%, rgba(239, 239, 239, 1) 91%, rgba(254, 254, 254, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#fefefe', GradientType=0);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group application-form-footer">
  <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6 checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="check"><span>Я согласен.</span></label>
  </div>
  <button id="submit-form" class="col-sm-offset-3 application-form-footer__button checkout" type="submit" disabled>
           Отправить
        </button>
</div>
```

Также хотелось бы добавить плавности перехода от одного состояния в другое, но как это сделать я не знаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'disabled'` должно быть строкой, а вы написали его без кавычек, можно и так, но тогда должна быть переменная с таким именем (`var disabled = 'disabled';`).

`btn.classList.add('button_checkin');` - тут название класса должно быть без точки в начале

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('submit-form');
document.getElementById('check').onclick = function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    // если checked, то применить новые стили к кнопке и отключить атрибут "disabled"...
    btn.removeAttribute('disabled');
    btn.classList.add('button_checkin');

  } else {
    btn.setAttribute('disabled', '');
    btn.classList.remove('button_checkin');
    // если не checked, то снять новые стили.
  }
};
```

```css
input+span {
  display: inline;
  line-height: normal;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode', sans-serif;
  font-size: .8em;
  color: #333;
}

.application-form-footer__button {
  cursor: default;
  width: 278px;
  height: 55px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode', sans-serif;
  color: #a1a2a7;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 241, 234, 0.55);
  -webkit-border-radius: 17px;
  -moz-border-radius: 17px;
  -ms-border-radius: 17px;
  border-radius: 17px;
  background: #efeef3;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#efeef3 0%, #eeedf2 11%, #ecebf0 13%, #edecf2 15%, #e6e7ec 38%, #e8e7ed 45%, #dddee3 66%, #dddee3 75%, #dbdce1 77%, #e1e2e7 91%, #ecedf2 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#efeef3 0%, #eeedf2 11%, #ecebf0 13%, #edecf2 15%, #e6e7ec 38%, #e8e7ed 45%, #dddee3 66%, #dddee3 75%, #dbdce1 77%, #e1e2e7 91%, #ecedf2 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#efeef3 0%, #eeedf2 11%, #ecebf0 13%, #edecf2 15%, #e6e7ec 38%, #e8e7ed 45%, #dddee3 66%, #dddee3 75%, #dbdce1 77%, #e1e2e7 91%, #ecedf2 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(#efeef3 0%, #eeedf2 11%, #ecebf0 13%, #edecf2 15%, #e6e7ec 38%, #e8e7ed 45%, #dddee3 66%, #dddee3 75%, #dbdce1 77%, #e1e2e7 91%, #ecedf2 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#efeef3', endColorstr='#ecedf2', GradientType=0);
}

.button_checkin {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #000;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(253, 253, 253, 1) 11%, rgba(246, 246, 246, 1) 28%, rgba(245, 245, 245, 1) 49%, rgba(241, 241, 241, 1) 51%, rgba(240, 240, 240, 1) 53%, rgba(234, 234, 234, 1) 66%, rgba(232, 232, 232, 1) 77%, rgba(239, 239, 239, 1) 91%, rgba(254, 254, 254, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(253, 253, 253, 1) 11%, rgba(246, 246, 246, 1) 28%, rgba(245, 245, 245, 1) 49%, rgba(241, 241, 241, 1) 51%, rgba(240, 240, 240, 1) 53%, rgba(234, 234, 234, 1) 66%, rgba(232, 232, 232, 1) 77%, rgba(239, 239, 239, 1) 91%, rgba(254, 254, 254, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(253, 253, 253, 1) 11%, rgba(246, 246, 246, 1) 28%, rgba(245, 245, 245, 1) 49%, rgba(241, 241, 241, 1) 51%, rgba(240, 240, 240, 1) 53%, rgba(234, 234, 234, 1) 66%, rgba(232, 232, 232, 1) 77%, rgba(239, 239, 239, 1) 91%, rgba(254, 254, 254, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#fefefe', GradientType=0);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group application-form-footer">
  <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6 checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="check"><span>Я согласен.</span></label>
  </div>
  <button id="submit-form" class="col-sm-offset-3 application-form-footer__button checkout" type="submit" disabled>Отправить</button>
</div>
```

Вариант чутка покороче :

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('submit-form');
document.getElementById('check').onclick = function() {
  btn.disabled = !this.checked;
  btn.classList.toggle('button_checkin');
};
```

```css
input+span {
  display: inline;
  line-height: normal;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode', sans-serif;
  font-size: .8em;
  color: #333;
}

.application-form-footer__button {
  cursor: default;
  width: 278px;
  height: 55px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode', sans-serif;
  color: #a1a2a7;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 241, 234, 0.55);
  -webkit-border-radius: 17px;
  -moz-border-radius: 17px;
  -ms-border-radius: 17px;
  border-radius: 17px;
  background: #efeef3;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#efeef3 0%, #eeedf2 11%, #ecebf0 13%, #edecf2 15%, #e6e7ec 38%, #e8e7ed 45%, #dddee3 66%, #dddee3 75%, #dbdce1 77%, #e1e2e7 91%, #ecedf2 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#efeef3 0%, #eeedf2 11%, #ecebf0 13%, #edecf2 15%, #e6e7ec 38%, #e8e7ed 45%, #dddee3 66%, #dddee3 75%, #dbdce1 77%, #e1e2e7 91%, #ecedf2 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#efeef3 0%, #eeedf2 11%, #ecebf0 13%, #edecf2 15%, #e6e7ec 38%, #e8e7ed 45%, #dddee3 66%, #dddee3 75%, #dbdce1 77%, #e1e2e7 91%, #ecedf2 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(#efeef3 0%, #eeedf2 11%, #ecebf0 13%, #edecf2 15%, #e6e7ec 38%, #e8e7ed 45%, #dddee3 66%, #dddee3 75%, #dbdce1 77%, #e1e2e7 91%, #ecedf2 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#efeef3', endColorstr='#ecedf2', GradientType=0);
}

.button_checkin {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #000;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(253, 253, 253, 1) 11%, rgba(246, 246, 246, 1) 28%, rgba(245, 245, 245, 1) 49%, rgba(241, 241, 241, 1) 51%, rgba(240, 240, 240, 1) 53%, rgba(234, 234, 234, 1) 66%, rgba(232, 232, 232, 1) 77%, rgba(239, 239, 239, 1) 91%, rgba(254, 254, 254, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(253, 253, 253, 1) 11%, rgba(246, 246, 246, 1) 28%, rgba(245, 245, 245, 1) 49%, rgba(241, 241, 241, 1) 51%, rgba(240, 240, 240, 1) 53%, rgba(234, 234, 234, 1) 66%, rgba(232, 232, 232, 1) 77%, rgba(239, 239, 239, 1) 91%, rgba(254, 254, 254, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(253, 253, 253, 1) 11%, rgba(246, 246, 246, 1) 28%, rgba(245, 245, 245, 1) 49%, rgba(241, 241, 241, 1) 51%, rgba(240, 240, 240, 1) 53%, rgba(234, 234, 234, 1) 66%, rgba(232, 232, 232, 1) 77%, rgba(239, 239, 239, 1) 91%, rgba(254, 254, 254, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#fefefe', GradientType=0);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group application-form-footer">
  <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6 checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="check"><span>Я согласен.</span></label>
  </div>
  <button id="submit-form" class="col-sm-offset-3 application-form-footer__button checkout" type="submit" disabled>Отправить</button>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, очень хорошее замечание, всё понятно. Если знаете: как добавить transition для плавности (в том варианте что №1)?

Comment: тут я вам точно не скажу, как правильно, но можно сделать так : `#submit-form {  transition: all 1s; }`, вродь работает )